# How to load date with custom format in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario where I have a column data like `"Tuesday, 09-Aug-11 21:13:26 GMT"` and I want to create a schema in Spark but the datatypes `TimestampType` and `DateType` is not able to recognize this date format.

After loading the data to a dataframe using `TimestampType` or `DateType` I am seeing `NULL` values in that particular column.

Is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to read "Tuesday, 09-Aug-11 21:13:26 GMT" as string type column & do transformation from string to timestamp something like below.

```
df.show(truncate=false)
+-------------------------------+
|dt                             |
+-------------------------------+
|Tuesday, 09-Aug-11 21:13:26 GMT|
+-------------------------------+
```

```
df.withColumn("dt",to_timestamp(col("dt"),"E, d-MMM-y H:m:s z")).show(truncate=false) //Note -  It is converted GMT to IST local timezone.

+-------------------+
|dt                 |
+-------------------+
|2011-08-10 02:43:26|
+-------------------+
```